# How to position my image on a canvas by positioning

Tags: javascript, qt, canvas, qml

I want to draw my image to the following anchored positions. How can I achieve this with Context2d::drawImage()? I purposefully placed it (0,0) btw.

```
anchors.right:  parent.right
anchors.top: parent.top
anchors.rightMargin: -10
```

---

```
    Canvas {
        anchors.fill: parent

        onPaint: {

            var ctx = getContext('2d');
            ctx.save();
            ctx.canvas.width = 160;
            ctx.canvas.height = 432;
            ctx.font = "18px Ubuntu";
            ctx.textAlign = "center";
            ctx.fillStyle = "#000000"

            const centerX = 10;
            const centerY = ctx.canvas.height / 2;
            const angle = Math.PI;
            const radius = 130
            ctx.fillStyle = "#000000"
            ctx.restore();
            
      

            ctx.save();
            ctx.drawImage(abcBar, 0, 0, abcBar.width, abcBar.height);
            console.log('loaded')
            ctx.restore();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<div style="display:none;">
  <img id="source"
       src="https://picsum.photos/200"
       width="220" height="277">
</div>


<script>
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const image = document.getElementById('source');

image.addEventListener('load', e => {
  //ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  ctx.drawImage(image, 33, 71, 104, 124, 21, 20, 87, 104);
  
//The source image is taken from the coordinates (33, 71), with a width of 104 
//and a height of 124. It is drawn to the canvas at (21, 20), where it is given      
//width of 87 and a height of 104.
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain this? How does this translate into `anchors.right:  parent.right`
`anchors.top: parent.top`

Comment: Detailed explanation is available at MDN Docs - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage

Comment: Yes I understand. But I want to get the coordinates of the top left most coordinates. The same as doing an `anchors.right:  parent.right anchors.top: parent.top`